# Figuring out GroupBy in this code snippet

Tags: c#, linq

I have a piece of code that I am struggling with figuring out. Not sure what's going on. It should return the most occurring numbers within an array (and it does).
It outputs the following => [2, 3].
I have tried to make my questions as readable as possible, sorry for any eye-strain.

I am struggling to understand the following code:

```
.GroupBy(..., numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key),
.OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key)
.First()
```

Could someone help explain this code to me?
I will write down comments inside of the code as far as I have understood it.

```
int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 };

// First in GroupBy(x => x) I group all numbers within the array (remove all
// duplicates too?), now my array looks like this [1,2,3,4].
int[] result = numbers1.GroupBy(x => x)
// In GroupBy(numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Count()) I collect all the
// different amount of occurrences withing the array, that would be 1 (1, 4)
// and 2 for (2, 3) so my array should look like this now [1, 2].
// Now this is where things get out of hand, what happens at the rest of it? I
// have tried for 4 hours now and can't figure it out. What exactly happens in
// numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key? .OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key)?
.GroupBy(numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Count(), numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key)
.OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key)
.First()
.ToArray();
```

Comment: The documentation of `GroupBy` has several examples. The [two argument version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___0___2__) seems to be the most relevant in your case.

Comment: First of all, what's your intention to do with this array? Without knowing your intention we are helpless to you because we don't know what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code with my comments:

```
int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 };

// First in GroupBy(x => x) all numbers are grouped by their values, so now data is IGrouping<int, int> query like this (formatted as a dict for readability in format {key: value}): {1: [1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4]} - int is key, value is occurrences list.
int[] result = numbers1.GroupBy(x => x)
// again, do GroupBy by elements count in group. You will get something like this: {1: [1, 4], 2: [2, 3]} - elements count is key, value is array of prev keys
.GroupBy(numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Count(), numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key)
// sort groups by elements count descending: {2: [2, 3], 1: [1, 4]}
.OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key)
// select group with max key (2): [2, 3]
.First()
// create array from this group: [2, 3]
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingvar, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for. So Key creates "groups" for values, interesting.

Comment: But what is the point of having both numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Count() AND  numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key though? Why isn't only numbersGroup.Count() enough?

Comment: No, you need to keep value from initial array too, `numbersGroup.Key` is it. This LINQ query returns values from initial array, not maximum ocurrences count

Comment: So Count() checks how many times a number, so if 2 and 3 occurs 2 times each, numbersGroup.Key will put them in one group of their own?
I'm sorry but I am not sure if I have understood it right.

Comment: `{1: [1], 2: [2, 2], 3: [3, 3], 4: [4]}`: for example, group will be `2: [2, 2]`, `2` is the `numbersGroup.Key`, `[2, 2]` is value, so `numbersGroup.Count()` will return `[2, 2]`.Count() => 2, so after this `GroupBy` collection will be `{2: [2, 3], 1: [1, 4]}` (key is value length, value is array of keys)

Answer (score 0):

Every once in a while, I'll come across code that has a lot of chaining, like:

```
int[] noIdeaWhyThisIsAnArray = Something.DosomethingElse().AndThenAnotherThing().Etc();
```

Whenever I have trouble understanding this, I break it into steps and use the "var" keyword to simplify things:

```
var step1 = Something.DosomethingElse();
var step2 = step1.AndThenAnotherThing();
var step3 = step2.Etc();
```

Then add a breakpoint after step3 is assigned, run the debugger/application, and then start checking out the variables in the Locals tab. In your case, the code would look like:

```
int[] numbers1 = { 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4 };

var step1 = numbers1.GroupBy(x => x);
var step2 = step1.GroupBy(numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Count(), numbersGroup => numbersGroup.Key);
var step3 = step2.OrderByDescending(supergroup => supergroup.Key);
var step4 = step3.First();
var step5 = step4.ToArray();
```

[image: Screenshot of Locals tab in the debugger]

That said, to answer your specific question:

The first GroupBy simply creates groups of each value/number. So all the 1s go into the first group, then all the 2s go into the next group, all the 3s go into the next group, etc... For example, in the screenshot, you can see the second group has two entries in it - both of them containing "2".

So at this point, there are a total of 4 groups (because there are 4 unique values). Two of the groups have 1 value each, and then the other two groups have 2 values each.

The next step then groups them by that count, so you end up with two groups, where the key indicates how many of each item there are. So the first group has a key of 1, and two values - "1" and "4", which means "1" and "4" both showed up once. The second group has a key of 2, and two values - "2" and "3", which means that "2" and "3" both showed up twice.

The third step orders that result in descending order of the key (and remember, the key indicates how many times those values showed up), so the MOST-frequently-occurring number(s) will be the first element in the result, and the LEAST-frequently-occurring number(s) will be the last element in the result.

The fourth step just takes that first result, which again, is the list of MOST-frequently-occurring numbers, in this case "2" and "3".

Finally, the fifth step takes that list and converts it to an array so instead of it being a Linq grouping object, it's just a simple array of those two numbers.

Comment: Dang man, great advice, Thanks a lot for taking your time writing  all of this down, I appreciate it. Yeah I am a newbie, I bet this will help me a lot, thanks!